# FindIndex() method rejecting object as predicate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
List<Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.allIndex> indicesAndValues = indicesAndValuesIE.ToList();
List<Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.allIndex> indicesAndValuesToExclude = new List<Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.allIndex>();

foreach (Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.allIndex indiceValue in indicesAndValues)
{
   if (indiceValue.value == "")
   {
      indicesAndValuesToExclude.Add(indiceValue);           
   }
}

int idd;
foreach (Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.allIndex removeObj in indicesAndValuesToExclude)
{
idd = indicesAndValues.FindIndex(removeObj);
}
```

Based on the code above,

```
idd = indicesAndValues.FindIndex(removeObj);
```

I want to retrieve the index in this List that has the element removeObj;

I am getting a error saying that FindIndex has some invalid argument.

removeObj and  indicesAndValues are of the same type except that indicesAndValues  is a List and removeObj is just a object of the same type

Why I am not able to use removeObj  as a predicate for the condition?

Answer (score 1):

`FindIndex` requires a predicate as parameter. You can use a lambda expression in order to specify a predicate

```
idd = indicesAndValues.FindIndex(item => item == removeObj);
```

You would use it in more complex scenarios like

```
idd = indicesAndValues.FindIndex(item => item.Name == "abc");
```

(This would find the index of the first item having a name of "abc".)

`List<T>` has another method `IndexOf` that you can use to find an object

```
idd = indicesAndValues.IndexOf(removeObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a predicate to `FindIndex`.

```
idd = indicesAndValues.FindIndex(o => o == removeObj);
```

A better alternative is using:

```
idd = indicesAndValues.IndexOf(removeObj);
```

Finally, in case you don't need to know which values were removed, you can rewrite your whole code to:

```
indicesAndValues.RemoveAll(obj => obj.Value == "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx) instead. [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9.aspx) takes a predicate, not a direct object. If you only want to find an object, `IndexOf` is a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
idd = indicesAndValues.FindIndex(o => o == removeObj);
```